# sql select statement using patterns instead of like

Tags: sql

I've a number in my database like 99999, 17299999, 182317299999 and I don't want to use `like '%99999'`. The patterns are 17_99999 and 18__17_99999.

Is there any way to use this patterns instead of like ? a.id = '17_'+b.id or something ?

PS. I have 60 mil records .. so using `like` is very nasty

Comment: You'll get more detail if you give more information about your particular situation.

Comment: That is my exact situation ... i have to select rows from table based on that patterns

Comment: You didn't say there are 60 million rows for a start. The core issue may well be that the column with these characters should actually be in a number of database column, which could then be indexed/searched on properly. You're always going to have to apply a string manipulation to your 60 million rows.

Comment: so there is no quicked solution ?

Comment: This is a design issue, if the data has meaning in some subset of the field and you want to search by it, then it should be stored in a separate field. then teh manipualtion is only done once at the time the record is inserted or if the field is updated, not in every search. It is critical to never design fields that contain multiple pieces of information when you want to search on a part. Especially when you have large tables.

Comment: I think I will use RIGHT function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you don't want to use `Like` but...

`like` supports single character place holders by using underscore, or character sets by using `[]` sets.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) page for more

In addition, don't forget that Like also supports using variables,

so you can do

```
declare @like varchar(200)
set @like = '17_99999'
select * from table where field like @like
```

This would allow you to build up your `@like` variable in a similar way to how you describe.

Comment: man .. using like takes like forever .. I have 60 milion records